# Android open flash panoramas

Tags: android

I have some 360 panoramas in .mov format (flash). 
Is there any way to open this panoramas in webView or even in an external site or using any library?
please help, thanx.

Comment: .mov isn't flash, it's QuickTime: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_File_Format